# How can I see what my java program is using memory for?

Tags: java, memory-management, ram

I wrote a program that used to work fine but at one point in time it startet to lag malfunction and become very slow. I thought it had to do because it was connected to a distant MySQL server and no longer to the localhost server it had been running on before. (that change happened around the same time)

So today I decided I want to test out if I could revert the change and connected it back to the server running in localhost only to find that it didn't change a thing. I even had to end the program with the task manager.

At this point I saw that my program was using over 2GB of RAM and 44% of the cpu, which before was around 60MB and 1%. I have no idea why and I would like to find out and look deeper into the memory usage of my program other  than just the total amount. Is there a way I can check what the memory is used for in a way a human can understand?

Comment: what language is the program written in? many development environments provide ways to profile memory and cpu consumption.

Comment: ahh forgot that, edited it. It's written in java

Comment: You can use `jconsole` and `jstack` to help understand.

Comment: I will look into that!

Comment: This article might help: [Java Memory Profiling Simplified](https://dzone.com/articles/java-memory-model-simplified)